# i want to convert String into Json string in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, sharedpreferences, jsondecoder

I have decoded my `response.body` i.e  `var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);` and its working fine
But when i convert it into object and saved into local storage using `sharedpref` like this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonData['categoryList'].forEach((data) => {
            categoryList.add(new ExpertCategory(
                id: jsonData['_id'],
                color: jsonData['color'],
                type: jsonData['category_name'],
                icon: ":)"))
          });
      print(categoryList) ;   
      localStorage.setCategoryData(categoryList.toString());
```

It stored in it And whenever i try to decode this its not working i.e

```
 localStorage.getCategoryData().then((data) => {
         userMap =  jsonDecode(data),
          
        });

class LocalStorage {
Future setCategoryData(data) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('category', data);
  
  }

  Future getCategoryData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final category = prefs.getString('category');
    return category;
  }
}
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ExpertCategory {
  final String  id;
  final String  type;
  final String  icon;
  final String  color;

const ExpertCategory( {
                  @required this.id,
                  @required this.type,
                  @required this.icon,
                  @required this.color,
                });
}
```

its not the same as before,its showing error and after fixing some 1st element of string '['
is showing. please help with this thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? also try printing the type of the variable before passing it through jsonDecode just to make sure it's actually string, data.runtimeType
refer to: https://programming-idioms.org/idiom/94/print-type-of-variable/2210/dart
if it's string, try printing it, make sure it's a valid json

Comment: Please share the full code of your localStorage class showing the methods you are using to store the data and how they are retrieved.

Comment: @AliAlNoaimi
userMap = jsonEncode(data),
  userMap1 =  jsonDecode(userMap),
   print( userMap1[0]),
I/flutter (25831): [

if i do this under that fuction
 userMap1 =  jsonDecode(data),
  print( userMap1[0]),

gives this
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter (25831): [Instance of 'ExpertCategory', Instance of 'ExpertCategory', Instance of 'E..

Comment: @JayParmar Provide the full code of the class ExpertCategory

Comment: @Omotayo4i i hv updated my comment please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ExpertCategory model to this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpertCategory {
  String id;
  String type;
  String icon;
  String color;

  ExpertCategory(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.type,
      @required this.icon,
      @required this.color});

  ExpertCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    type = json['type'];
    icon = json['icon'];
    color = json['color'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['icon'] = this.icon;
    data['color'] = this.color;
    return data;
  }
}
```

For your `LocalStorage` class, there are two approaches to setting your data into `SharedPreferences`. One using `setString`, the other being `setStringList` since you are storing the list of categories.

Checkout both approaches below.

**APPROACH 1**

```
class LocalStorage {
  Future setCategoryData(List<ExpertCategory> data) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(
        'category', jsonEncode(data.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()));
  }

  Future<List<ExpertCategory>> getCategoryData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final category = prefs.getString('category');
    return List<ExpertCategory>.from(
        List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(category))
            .map((e) => ExpertCategory.fromJson(e))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
class LocalStorage {
  Future setCategoryData(List<ExpertCategory> data) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('category',
        List<String>.from(data.map((e) => jsonEncode(e.toJson())).toList()));
  }

  Future<List<ExpertCategory>> getCategoryData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final category = prefs.getStringList('category');
    return List<ExpertCategory>.from(
        category.map((e) => ExpertCategory.fromJson(jsonDecode(e))).toList());
  }
}
```

And finally you set your data into the `SharedPreferences` using

```
localStorage.setCategoryData(categoryList);
```